# Handling Dot (.) Parameters in Java Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to format my REST interface as follows:

myurl.com/resources/{resourceId}

I optionally want people to be able to provide the following variations to specify return formats:

myurl.com/resources.json/{resourceId}

I am using Jersey to provide my REST services. What is the best way to handle these parameters?

Should a create a separate class with a different @PATH notation, or can I have a single class and parse out that parameter? Are there any built in annotations that might handle this, similar to @PathParam or @QueryParam?

Comment: Return format would probably be better handled in the accepts header.

Comment: I want to use this, much like Google uses the alt parameter in the YouTube API. I prefer this notation.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

Answer (score 0):

There already is a mechanism for this (as @digitaljoel already stated) - HTTP Accept header.

Jersey doesn't have any direct support for your usecase, but there is something similar - media type mapping feature, see 
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS
and
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#getMediaTypeMappings%28%29

Unfortunately for you it handles only URLs which have this "param" at the end, but it should not be very hard to take UriConnegFilter sources (http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/UriConnegFilter.java?rev=5698) and modify it to suit your needs.